# Starting from 1 how far can I count, when I can use any digit a maximum of N times

Tags: java, algorithm

My problem is as follows; for number N, I need to find out what is the largest value I can count to, when each digit can be used N times.

For example if N = 5, the largest value is 12, since at that point the digit 1 has been used 5 times.

My original approach was to simply iterate through all numbers and keep a tally of how many times each digit has been used so far. This is obviously very inefficient when N is large, so am looking for advice on what would be a smarter (and more efficient) way to achieve this.

```
public class Counter {

    private static Hashtable<Integer, Integer> numbers;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Counter c = new Counter();
        c.run(9);
    }

    public Counter() {
        numbers = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

        numbers.put(0, 0);
        numbers.put(1, 0);
        numbers.put(2, 0);
        numbers.put(3, 0);
        numbers.put(4, 0);
        numbers.put(5, 0);
        numbers.put(6, 0);
        numbers.put(7, 0);
        numbers.put(8, 0);
        numbers.put(9, 0);

    }

    public static void run(int maxRepeat) {

        int keeper = 0;

        for(int maxFound = 0; maxFound <= maxRepeat; maxFound++) {
            keeper++;
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.toString(keeper).length(); i++) {
                int a = Integer.toString(keeper).charAt(i);
                 //here update the tally for appropriate digit and check if max repeats is reached
                }
            }

        System.out.println(keeper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would you use this algorithm for?  Just curious.

Comment: And using a Hashtable will make it even more inefficient. Use HashMap instead.

Comment: If i got your question right, you can safely ignore all numbers but 1. 1 will __always__  be the greatest, if you start to count from 1.

Comment: @MouseEvent That's what I thought too, at first, but really the question is how high can you count without using any given digit more than N times. If N is 13, for example, you can get to 21 before using 13 1's, but you don't use any more 1's until you get to 31. And you can get to 29 while using only 13 2's. So for N=13, the answer should be 30. It's not enough to _just_ keep track of the 1's. Though I do believe that's the first step toward a better algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, rather than backing your `Counter` with a `Hashtable`, use an `int[]` instead. When you know exactly how many elements your map has to have, and especially when the keys are numbers, an array is perfect.

That being said, I think the most effective speedup is likely to come from better math, not better algorithms. With some experimentation (or it may be obvious), you'll notice that 1 is always the first digit to be used a given number of times. So given `N`, if you can find which number is the first to use the digit 1 `N+1` times, you know your answer is the number right *before* that. This would let you solve the problem without actually having to count that high.

Now, let's look at how many 1's are used counting up to various numbers. Throughout this post I will use `n` to designate a number when we are trying to figure out how many 1's are used to count up to a number, whereas capital `N` designates how many 1's are used to count up to something.

## One digit numbers

Starting with the single-digit numbers:

```
1:  1
2:  1
...
9:  1
```

Clearly the number of 1's required to count up to a one-digit number is... 1. Well, actually we forgot one:

```
0:  0
```

That will be important later. So we should say this: the number of 1's required to count up to a one-digit number `X` is `X > 0 ? 1 : 0`. Let's define a mathematical function `f(n)` that will represent "number of 1's required to count up to `n`". Then

```
f(X) = X > 0 ? 1 : 0
```

## Two-digit numbers

For two-digit numbers, there are two types. For numbers of the form `1X`,

```
10: 2
11: 4
12: 5
...
19: 12
```

You can think of it like this: counting up to `1X` requires a number of 1's equal to

- `f(9)` (from counting up to 9) plus
- 1 (from 10) plus
- `X` (from the first digits of 11-`1X` inclusive, if `X > 0`) plus
- however many 1's were required to count up to `X`

Or mathematically,

```
f(1X) = f(9) + 1 + X + f(X)
```

Then there are the two-digit numbers higher than 19:

```
21: 13
31: 14
...
91: 20
```

The number of 1's required to count to a two-digit number `YX` with `Y > 1` is

- `f(19)` (from counting up to 19) plus
- `f(9) * (Y - 2)` (from the 1's in numbers 20 through `(Y-1)9` inclusive - like if `Y = 5`, I mean the 1's in 20-49, which come from 21, 31, 41) plus
- however many 1's were required to count up to `X`

Or mathematically, for `Y > 1`,

```
f(YX) = f(19) + f(9) * (Y - 2) + f(X)
      = f(9) + 1 + 9 + f(9) + f(9) * (Y - 2) + f(X)
      = 10 + f(9) * Y + f(X)
```

## Three-digit numbers

Once you get into three-digit numbers, you can kind of extend the pattern. For any three-digit number of the form `1YX` (and now `Y` can be anything), the total count of 1's from counting up to that number will be

- `f(99)` (from counting up to 99) plus
- 1 (from 100) plus
- `10 * Y + X` (from the first digits of 101-`1YX` inclusive) plus
- however many 1's were required to count up to `YX` in two-digit numbers

so

```
f(1YX) = f(99) + 1 + YX + f(YX)
```

Note the parallel to `f(1X)`. Continuing the logic to more digits, the pattern, for numbers which start with 1, is

```
f(1[m-digits]) = f(10^m - 1) + 1 + [m-digits] + f([m-digits])
```

with `[m-digits]` representing a sequence of digits of length `m`.

Now, for three-digit numbers `ZYX` that don't start with 1, i.e. `Z > 1`, the number of 1's required to count up to them is

- `f(199)` (from counting up to 199) plus
- `f(99) * (Z - 2)` (from the 1's in 200-`(Z-1)99` inclusive) plus
- however many 1's were required to count up to `YX`

so

```
f(ZYX) = f(199) + f(99) * (Z - 2) + f(YX)
       = f(99) + 1 + 99 + f(99) + f(99) * (Z - 2) + f(YX)
       = 100 + f(99) * Z + f(YX)
```

And the pattern for numbers that don't start with 1 now seems to be clear:

```
f(Z[m-digits]) = 10^m + f(10^m - 1) * Z + f([m-digits])
```

## General case

We can combine the last result with the formula for numbers that do start with 1. You should be able to verify that the following formula is equivalent to the appropriate case given above for all digits `Z` 1-9, and that it does the right thing when `Z == 0`:

```
f(Z[m-digits]) = f(10^m - 1) * Z + f([m-digits])
                                + (Z > 1) ? 10^m : Z * ([m-digits] + 1)
```

And for numbers of the form `10^m - 1`, like 99, 999, etc. you can directly evaluate the function:

```
f(10^m - 1) = m * 10^(m-1)
```

because the digit 1 is going to be used `10^(m-1)` times in each of the `m` digits - for example, when counting up to 999, there will be 100 1's used in the hundreds' place, 100 1's used in the tens' place, and 100 1's used in the ones' place. So this becomes

```
f(Z[m-digits]) = Z * m * 10^(m-1) + f([m-digits])
                                  + (Z > 1) ? 10^m : Z * ([m-digits] + 1)
```

You can tinker with the exact expression, but I think this is pretty close to as good as it gets, for this particular approach anyway. What you have here is a recursion relation that allows you to evaluate `f(n)`, the number of 1's required to count up to `n`, by stripping off a leading digit at each step. Its time complexity is *logarithmic* in `n`.

## Implementation

Implementing this function is straightforward given the last formula above. You can technically get away with one base case in the recursion: the empty string, i.e. define `f("")` to be 0. But it will save you a few calls to also handle single digits as well as numbers of the form `10^m - 1`. Here's how I'd do it, omitting a bit of argument validation:

```
private static Pattern nines = Pattern.compile("9+");

/** Return 10^m for m=0,1,...,18 */
private long pow10(int m) {
    // implement with either pow(10, m) or a switch statement
}

public long f(String n) {
    int Z = Integer.parseInt(n.substring(0, 1));
    int nlen = n.length();
    if (nlen == 1) {
        return Z > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (nines.matcher(n).matches()) {
        return nlen * pow10(nlen - 1);
    }
    String m_digits = n.substring(1);
    int m = nlen - 1;
    return Z * m * pow10(m - 1) + f_impl(m_digits)
        + (Z > 1 ? pow10(m) : Z * (Long.parseLong(m_digits) + 1));
}
```

## Inverting

This algorithm solves the inverse of the the question you're asking: that is, it figures out how many times a digit is used counting up to `n`, whereas you want to know which `n` you can reach with a given number `N` of digits (i.e. 1's). So, as I mentioned back in the beginning, you're looking for the first `n` for which `f(n+1) > N`.

The most straightforward way to do this is to just start counting up from `n = 0` and see when you exceed `N`.

```
public long howHigh(long N) {
    long n = 0;
    while (f(n+1) <= N) { n++; }
    return n;
}
```

But of course that's no better (actually probably worse) than accumulating counts in an array. The whole point of having `f` is that you don't have to test every number; you can jump up by large intervals until you find an `n` such that `f(n+1) > N`, and then narrow down your search using the jumps. A reasonably simple method I'd recommend is [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) to put an upper bound on the result, followed by a binary search to narrow it down:

```
public long howHigh(long N) {
    long upper = 1;
    while (f(upper + 1) <= N) {
        upper *= 2;
    }
    long lower = upper / 2, mid = -1;
    while (lower < upper) {
        mid = (lower + upper) / 2;
        if (f(mid + 1) > N) {
            upper = mid;
        }
        else {
            lower = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return lower;
}
```

Since the implementation of `f` from above is O(log(n)) and exponential+binary search is also O(log(n)), the final algorithm should be something like O(log^2(n)), and I think the relation between N and n is linear enough that you could consider it O(log^2(N)) too. If you search in log space and judiciously cache computed values of the function, it might be possible to bring it down to roughly O(log(N)). A variant that *might* provide a significant speedup is sticking in a round of [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) after determining the upper bound, but that's tricky to code properly. Fully optimizing the search algorithm is probably a matter for another question though.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this so thoroughly. However I am pretty new to creating algorithms, and even with this explanation, am having some difficulties. So if you have any further pointers on how to go about implementing this, please share.

Comment: OK, can you elaborate on what exactly you're having trouble with?

Comment: actually I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should be more efficient. Use integer array of size 10 to keep the count of digits.

```
public static int getMaxNumber(int N) {
    int[] counts = new int[10];
    int number = 0;
    boolean limitReached = false;
    while (!limitReached) {
        number++;
        char[] digits = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();
        for (char digit : digits) {
            int count = counts[digit - '0'];
            count++;
            counts[digit - '0'] = count;
            if (count >= N) {
                limitReached = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** As @Modus Tollens mentioned initial code has a bug. When `N = 3` it returns `11`, but there are four `1`s between `1 and 11`. The fix is to check if limit is breached `count[i] > N` on given number, previous number should be return. But if for some `i` `count[i] == N` for other `j` `count[j] <= N`, the actual number should be returned.

Please see corresponding code below:

```
public static int getMaxNumber(int N) {
    int[] counts = new int[10];
    int number = 0;
    while (true) {
        number++;
        char[] digits = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();

        boolean limitReached = false;
        for (char digit : digits) {
            int count = counts[digit - '0'];
            count++;
            counts[digit - '0'] = count;

            if (count == N) {
                //we should break loop if some count[i] equals to N
                limitReached = true;
            } else if (count > N) {
                //previous number should be returned immediately
                //, if current number gives more unique digits than N
                return number - 1;
            }
        }
        if (limitReached) {
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** As @David Z and @Modus Tollens mentioned, in case if `N=13`, 30 should be returned, ie, algo stops when N is breached but not reached. If this is initial requirement, the code will be even simpler:

```
 public static int getMaxNumber(int N) {
    int[] counts = new int[10];
    int number = 0;
    while (true) {
        number++;
        char[] digits = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();
        for (char digit : digits) {
            int count = counts[digit - '0'];
            count++;
            counts[digit - '0'] = count;
            if (count > N) {
                return number - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this fail for some numbers? E.g. for `N = 1` I can count to 9  (method returns 1) and for `N = 3` I can count to 10 (method returns 11). And as David Z demonstrated in the comments, `N = 13` should return 30 instead of 21.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, you are right. I will update the post to fix this issue

Comment: @AntonDovzhenko thank you for taking the time to post this. However, unfortunately the values of N I am looking at are in the quadrillions, and for that I think even this approach is too slow.